# sending info back along a chain of scripts

Tags: multithreading, powershell

i have a couple of scripts.
one that takes in alot of data from AD (like every username) and doles out sections to multiple instances another script up to a limit. i am using jobs for this.

i got everything working as intended except for one thing, during the loops of the second script, i would like to send a piece of data back on the progress to the parent script to help report of the current progress of the script overall.

can someone provide a simple example of how to send data back to the parent script multiple times (for each loop of code in the child) so that it can be written out via a write-host onto the parent console window?

I have powershell 4 installed, though would prefer a version 3 solution. I also have quest cmdlets. nothing else to fancy to mention.

please and thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See if this helps:

[Powershell parallel jobs output file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20112534/powershell-parallel-jobs-output-file/20119938#20119938)

You can retrieve information from the child job output buffers, and then use .clear() on the buffer to remove the output you've already grabbed, so that the next read is always new data.  The output gets copied to the parent job as it's created, so you can do this and still run Receive-Job when the job completes and still get all the job data, in the order it was created from all the various output buffers.

Comment: thanks, i won't have time to test this right away but seems close to what i have been told by other sources, so will probably work for my needs. Something that would help to know as well is editing variables in the parent script from the child, can the scope of variables be opened that far in Powershell?

Comment: You use values read from the child jobs to set values in your main script.  Those are running in separate runspaces.  There isn't really a "scope" issue involved, since they're completely different call stacks.

Comment: since i finally got around to implementing this, i just wanted to say thanks again. your aid was most beneficial.
i had to do some more digging on the specifics of what was mentioned, but it got me on the right track and it all works now.

Comment: Have a look at this:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20112534/powershell-parallel-jobs-output-file/20119938#20119938

Comment: thanks, it looks quite nice, though not alot for examples in the docs.
i pass in my script block, my snappin(quest AD), and have my Array of values piping in seemingly fine though how do i debug the code i pass to the process and how do i grab the processed list of items back?

Comment: i just discovered that the PSobject i piped into the Split-Pipeline was getting modified directly as i added properties and data to the object.
thought there would be a scope issue here.
this saved me alot of typing.
though if i can get an answer for the  question stated in the above comment for future reference, that would be great. :)
also is there a way to get a progress bar out of it?

Comment: Haven't tested, but Progress is one of the output buffers that can be read.